# Floating Notification Dialog Android

Tags: java, notifications, android

I am trying to create a notification (to prompt a user to click on a button or indicate its functionality) in a sort of tutorial phase. My (very rough) mockup is as so:

[image]

Ideally, it would be floating over the activity and maybe stay for 2-3 seconds (or click to dismiss type action).

I don't think this would work well with a Toast (as it can't really point to anything). Also, if I don't want it to disappear and only do a tap to dismiss (either by clicking the ImageButton it's pointing to or the notif itself), I can't do that with a toast.

A dialog wouldn't work either.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: These days I see quite a few Android applications do this. Wondering how it works! Not sure if you found the answer elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try using an alert dialog?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("your title")
.setMessage("message you want to show to the user")
.setPositiveButton("Settings",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
//your action to dismiss this dialog

}).show();
```

Comment: I don't want it on the center of the screen and I don't want buttons. Thanks for the suggestion, though.